# Sql Server takes too much time to load

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

I have a query where it gets all the data of each day per hour of the month and when I run it in sql server it's taking too much time that I get Timeout error in my web reporting. is there any other way to query and get the same result?

```
SELECT DISTINCT  CONCAT(date,' ',FORMAT(CAST([dbo].[TALAGA_PL70_FEEDER_1].time as datetime) , 'HH')) as Time, 
              [dbo].[TALAGA_PL70_FEEDER_1].Ia, 
              [dbo].[TALAGA_PL70_FEEDER_1].Ib, 
              [dbo].[TALAGA_PL70_FEEDER_1].Ic, 
              [dbo].[TALAGA_PL70_FEEDER_1].Ineutral
          FROM [dbo].[TALAGA_PL70_FEEDER_1] 
          JOIN (
               SELECT CONCAT(date,' ',MIN(time)) as mints FROM [TALAGA_PL70_FEEDER_1]  
                WHERE (date >= '2019-04-26' 
                AND date  <= '2019-05-25')  
                GROUP BY date, DATEPART(hh, time)

            )tt 
          ON [dbo].[TALAGA_PL70_FEEDER_1].time = tt.mints AND [TALAGA_PL70_FEEDER_1].date = tt.mints
          ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

**Here's the sample sql result:**

```
Time          | Ia               | Ib                | Ic               |  Ineutral
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-04-26 00 | 169.809661865234 |  163.836029052734 | 157.159591674805 |  13.2650079727173
2019-04-26 01 | 159.619323730469 |  155.754028320313 | 149.516830444336 |  10.7174234390259
2019-04-26 02 | 152.855056762695 |  148.814056396484 | 140.819900512695 |  12.0351390838623
2019-04-26 03 | 146.969253540039 |  144.773056030273 | 135.900436401367 |  11.1566619873047
```

**Table Schema :**

```
GO
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TALAGA_PL70_FEEDER_1](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[date] [date] NOT NULL,
[time] [time](7) NOT NULL,
[Ineutral] [float] NULL,
[Ia] [float] NULL,
[Ib] [float] NULL,
[Ic] [float] NULL,
[Iave] [float] NULL,
[Ig] [float] NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY]

 GO
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TALAGA_PL70_FEEDER_1] ADD  CONSTRAINT 
 [DF__TALAGA_FEE__date__0F975522]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [date]
 GO
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TALAGA_PL70_FEEDER_1] ADD  CONSTRAINT 
 [DF__TALAGA_FEE__time__108B795B]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [time]
```

**The error I get in my web reporting:**

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08S01 [SQLSTATE] => 08S01 [1] => 258 [code] => 258 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Shared Memory Provider: Timeout error [258]. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Shared Memory Provider: Timeout error [258]. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 08S01 [SQLSTATE] => 08S01 [1] => 258 [code] => 258 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Communication link failure [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Communication link failure ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 08S01 [SQLSTATE] => 08S01 [1] => -2147467259 [code] => -2147467259 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Communication link failure [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Communication link failure ) )

Comment: Please don't post images of errors and data. Both are text are should be supplied as `text`. Include your data as formatted `text` or as DDL and DML statements, and your error within a quote box. Thanks.

Comment: Om a different note, including the schema name when referring to a column is deprecated and should be avoided. Ideally you should be aliasing your tables/views/result sets with an appropriate name and referring to that. For `[dbo].[TALAGA_PL70_FEEDER_1] ` perhaps `TPF1` would be a good alias.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. To help us, please post a schema (as text), and some sample data (also as text); a SQLFiddle would be perfect.

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand the intent of this query - I've created a SQLFiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/59b21/1) but the subquery makes no sense to me. What is its role?

Comment: It's getting the max value per hour. @NevilleKuyt

Comment: Nope, still don't get it - it appears to be a mechanism for getting a combination of valid date/hour combinations, for a given range of dates (2019-04-26' - '2019-05-25'), which are then joined back to the records. Is that the intention?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have just not included it, it appears your table has no indexes. I'm also assuming that there is more data than the month your query is addressing. So the query is having to look at the entire table every time. In fact its probably hitting the entire table twice, once in your inner query to create the hourly buckets, then again to determine which bucket to put each row in.

You might get some dissenting opinions on exactly how you should index, but if this was my db I would create a primary clustered index on the id column, then create a nonclustered index on date, including the time column.

You *might* also need to add a where clause to the outer query to filter to the same date range as the inner query.

Answer (score 0):

Try using window functions:

```
SELECT date,
       RIGHT('00' + DATENAME(hour, f.time), 2) as Time,
       f.Ia, f.Ib, f.Ic, f.Ineutral
FROM (SELECT f.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date, DATEPART(HOUR, f.time) ORDER BY f.time ASC) as seqnum
      FROM [dbo].[TALAGA_PL70_FEEDER_1] f
      WHERE date >= '2019-04-26' AND
            date <= '2019-05-25' 
     ) f
WHERE seqnum = 1;
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

Notes:

- I generally abhor mixing types, so I separated the date and hour into separate columns.
- `FORMAT()` is rumored to be much slower than other date/time functions, but I doubt that would have much impact on your timing.
- For performance, create an index on `date`.
- There is not much you can do about the `ROW_NUMBER()` unless you want to add a computed column.